# rubocop rspec ruby2.4-strict rule MultilineBlockLayout and NamedSubject conflict

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet, lint, rubocop

I have following rspec ruby code. I am testing some puppet modules. It throws a linting error.

`Block body expression is on the same line as the block start. (convention:Layout/MultilineBlockLayout)`

```
describe "on #{os}" do
  let(:facts) { facts }      

  it { is_expected.to contain_class('windows_some_thing::some_suite') }
  context 'with some_suite_enabled' do
    let(:params) { { cipher_suite: %w[ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ] } }

    it { is_expected.to contain_registry_value('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\something\something\something\000000\Functions').with(
        ensure: 'present',
        type: 'string',
        data: 'ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521,ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ',
      )
    }
  end
```

I can use `rubocop -a` to fix it. However this corrects the code as per below. And then get a different linting error

`Name your test subject if you need to reference it explicitly. (convention:RSpec/NamedSubject)`

```
    it {
      expect(subject).to contain_registry_value('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\something\something\something\000000\Functions').with(
        ensure: 'present',
        type: 'string',
        data: 'ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521,ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ',
      )
    }
```

How can I fix this for `ruby-2.4-strict`? I have more than 10000 linting errors I need to fix. spread across multiple files and modules. So I need a practical straight forward solution. I know it will be quite time consuming. But I don't want it to take rest of the year to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler and more direct correction for

> `Block body expression is on the same line as the block start.
>   (convention:Layout/MultilineBlockLayout)`

would involve this:

```
it {
  is_expected.to contain_registry_value('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\something\something\something\000000\Functions').with(
    ensure: 'present',
    type: 'string',
    data: 'ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521,ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ',
  )
}
```

The rule is that the start and end delimiters of a *multiline* block must appear on separate lines from anything (other than whitespace) in the block body.

That, too, will still raise a flag, but one whose correction is more evident.  The linter wants you to use `do` and `end` to delimit multiline blocks, so this is where you ultimately want to be:

```
it do
  is_expected.to contain_registry_value('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\something\something\something\000000\Functions').with(
    ensure: 'present',
    type: 'string',
    data: 'ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521,ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ',
  )
end
```

Or maybe even here:

```
it do
  is_expected.to contain_registry_value('HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\something\something\something\000000\Functions')
    .with(
      ensure: 'present',
      type: 'string',
      data: 'ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521,ABC_ECDHE_JKL_WITH_ABC_123_RET_ABC_384_521 ',
    )
end
```

I find this last more readable, especially if you want to chain additional predicates.

Comment: it would still complain about the subject needing to be explicit

Comment: found a not so desireable solution to make it all one line as oppose to multi line. Not so desireable in terms of readability though :-|

Comment: @MonteCristo, the form I present is idiomatic for Puppet rspec tests, whatever rubocop is telling you. Moreover, as run by `pdk validate`, rubocop *does not* complain about wanting an explicit subject.  I presume, therefore, that you're not using PDK, but you should nevertheless be able to adjust your rubocop configuration as PDK does.  Or convert your module to PDK and let it take care of that.